# Replacing values using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

What are the reasons why are regex replacment doesn't work? I have tried ensuring no excess spaces.

```
df.column
0    Test_With_Him
1    And_another option with him
2    and_another reason with her

replacement = {'_':' ',Test With': 'test with', 'and another': 'And another& AND'}
df['column'] = df.column.replace('\s+',' ' , regex=True).str.strip().replace(replacement, regex=True)
```

When I do `df.loc[df['column']=="and another reason with her"]` nothing has changed.

Comment: You did not assign the result back, `df.column = df.column....`

Comment: I did it in my original code but forgot to type it here, apologies. It still doesn't work

Comment: Can't repro, I get `And another& AND reason with her` instead of `and another reason with her`

Comment: Would you know any reasons why it could fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `df.replace(regex=dict)`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'test':["Test With Him","And Another option with him",'and another reason with her']})

replacement = {r'Test With': 'test with', r'And Another': 'And another& AND'}

df=df.replace(regex=replacement)

                        test
0                     test with Him
1  And another& AND option with him
2       and another reason with her
```

Comment: It should work. Worked for me.What version are you on? Why doesnt work? error?

Comment: It replace some of the items in the dictionary but not all the items. I can't understand why.

Comment: Modify you question and show what does not change and we can try to help. Maybe white space or case issues

Comment: Are you sorted or need more help?

Comment: `df=df.replace(replacement,regex=True)`

Comment: Yh sorted, it was because I had an item in the dictionary that replaced underscore with space. And I thought that meant the rest of items in the dictionary could be without the underscore given the underscore replacement was the first item in the dictionary. Thanks for your help